# Assign Employees to Manager in Moodle

Tags: moodle

In Moodle, I can see the following roles - Student and Manager. I have created 2 managers and 5 students. Is there a way to assign 3 students to 1 manager so that whenever these 2 students send any requests for approval, it will be shown only to their respective Manager?

Comment: Is this a request for a course enrolment or activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups may do the trick or get you close, especially if aiming to launch only a couple unique courses or activities across multiple managers:

https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/Groups

https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/Groups_FAQ

Thinking of "managers" as "teachers" and and "employees" as "students", you could setup groups so that each has a manager with employees, and you'd enable certain separations between teams of managers/employees.

As gnuwings mentioned, there are definitely limitations, for example, each Moodle activity (like a quiz, assignment, etc.) can implement groups differently, so usefulness likely will depend on your goals.

Cohorts are another option; these work across a site, but there are also limitations. Have found over time when cohorts are best, customization to accomplish course-specific quiz/assignment/grading/reporting activities by cohort is common.

Good luck on it!

Answer (score 1):

No such feature currently available in Moodle. Custom development is needed.